# Tab Bar controllers in iOS development. Why does it re-run all the code when I switch tabs?

Tags: ios, swift, tabs

So I'm creating an app with two tabs, created using a Tab Bar controller.

The tab bar controller is linked to a swift file while each tab is connected to their own swift file as well, for a grand total of 3  view controllers and 3 swift files (one for each)

I'll call them **tab1** and **tab2** and **tabcontroller**.

**Tab1** is an MkMapview and in addition to this has two asynchronous operations and a network operation as well. A lot of stuff goes on here. **Tab2** is a simple tableview (vertical scrolling list)

The problem is that every time I switch to **tab2** then switch back to **tab1**, it runs everything in **tab1** again which I don't want. I just want to user to be able to switch between the views and return to each and continue where they left off - just like a tab in a web browser.

I feel like what I want is simpler than what I have achieved using the tab method.

Comment: https://www.codementor.io/hemantkumar434/view-controller-lifecycle-ios-applications-7oyju9lp6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embed all the network logic inside

```
override func viewDidLoad {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   startRequest1()
   startRequest2()
}
```

as it's called once when the vc loads as opposed to `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear`  that called upon switching tabs

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it. I had some code in viewDidAppear and I moved it to viewDidLoad and now it works exactly the way I wanted to. I had no idea that viewDidLoad() is only called once despite switching tabs. Much appreciated!